# Can NestJS lifecycle methods run in parallel rather than in sequence?

Tags: nestjs

We have a number of "poller" class instances running on a dedicated deploy of our app. When SIGTERM is received, we want each of these pollers to gracefully shutdown. We've implemented an async `beforeApplicationShutdown` method on our base poller class to that effect.

For our use case, each of these methods can be run in parallel. But it seems they are run in sequence by NestJS.

A negative consequence of this behavior is that the app can take a long time to spin down. ECS gives us 30 seconds from SIGTERM to SIGKILL, which we could extend as we add more pollers, but I'd rather not lengthen our deploy times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a solution like this:

```js
const app: NestApplication;

// start the app, etc...

process.on('SIGTERM', async () => {
  const pollers = getAllPollers(app);
  // In parallel, shut down all pollers.
  await Promise.all(pollers.map((poller) => poller.stopPolling()));
  await app.close();
  process.exit(0);
});

function getAllPollers(app: NestApplication): BasePoller[] {
  const pollers: BasePoller[] = [];
  app
    .get(DiscoveryService)
    .getProviders()
    .forEach((instanceWrapper) => {
      const { instance } = instanceWrapper;
      if (instance instanceof BasePoller) {
        pollers.push(instance);
      }
    });
  return pollers;
}
```